# Avoiding java.util classes while debugging

Tags: java, debugging

While I am debugging and hit "Step into" at a point where I use an ArrayList, HashMap, or something like that, I go into the ArrayList.java class and have to go over so many iterations that I am not interested in. Aside from using "Step over", is there a way I can avoid java.util classes while I am debugging?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Eclipse, the Step Filtering Options can be adjusted as needed:

`Window` - `Preferences` - `Java` - `Debug` - `Step Filtering`

There the classes or packages can be set, that should not be stepped into.

> Step filters are commonly used to filter out types that you do not wish to see or step through while debugging.

I think IntelliJ IDEA has something similar...

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!